# Make spring security to allow users to download files with extension .pkg and .msi

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to make Spring Security allow users to download some static files from the server, however, I can see where it works for JS, CSS and images files.

When I try to get from the same folder a file .msi or .pkg, spring security shows me to the 404 page.

Somebody have an idea how can I prevent this or which configuration I'm missing here?

I've overridden the configure method as below, but it's not working for .msi and .pgk files

```
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**.msi");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**.pkg");
  }
```

UPDATE

I'm trying to access https://dev.server.com/app/resources/dummy/installers/XYZ.msi and when I access the following https://dev.server.com/app/resources/dummy/css/main.css I don't have any problems.

Seems to me it could be something related with the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping where I don't know how to add a mapping for .msi or .pkg files, because I see where all the files under 'resources' are expose but it must be like js, css and images.

This is a log when the application starts:

```
2017-02-23 17:44:37.178  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.js] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.178  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.css] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.179  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.png] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.179  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.180  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.gif] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.180  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.jpg] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.181  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.ttf] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.181  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.woff] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-23 17:44:37.182  INFO 10948 --- [localhost-startStop-1] SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(registerHandler:354) : Mapped URL path [/resources/**/*.woff2] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going to multiple solutions, I found that I need to add the extension overriding 'addResourceHandler', check the method below

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**/*.js", "/resources/**/*.css", "/resources/**/*.png",
                "/resources/**/*.ico", "/resources/**/*.gif", "/resources/**/*.jpg", "/resources/**/*.ttf",
                "/resources/**/*.woff", "/resources/**/*.woff2", "/resources/**/*.msi", "/resources/**/*.pkg").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```